# Some PES games only recognising 32MB VRAM?

Tags: technical-issues, hardware, graphics-card, pro-evolution-soccer-series

I bought a Lenovo Flex 2 - 15:

- **Graphics card:** Nvidia GeForce 840m with 4GB dedicated RAM.
- **OS:** Windows 8.1.

But in PES 2013's and PES 2009's settings, it is reporting that VRAM is only 32MB! I've tried updating my graphics drivers but that didn't help. It says :

> Your computer does not meet the minimum system requirements to run this software. As a result, you may experience errors during operating.
>
> Your video card does not meet the required specifications (GPU:VRAM 128mb)

Both PES 2013 and 2009 work properly on my second Windows PC (Win 7), and PES 2015 works properly on Windows 8.1.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

That's fine. Your laptop uses Shared Memory, so the GPU will use what free RAM you have. It has 32mb of dedicated VRAM, but much more memory available.

Your system should have no problems playing the game in question, though I'm not sure how well the performance will be.